# KivyMD MDNavigationRail, press icons

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I was trying to use a new feature in KivyMD, the MDNavigationRail and wanted to give the icons in it a function. The goal is that the user could change to the desired screen by pressing the icon that represents it. I gave the icon an `on_press`. But something goes wrong, I get an error; `ValueError: MDNavigationRail.state is set to an invalid option 'down'. Must be one of: ['close', 'open']`. The rail should be open or closed I guess, isn't it possible to give it a function? Furthermore, I would want to know if it is possible to not break the text. If anyone could help me out, it would be very nice!

**My .py file**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class Screen1(MDScreen):
    def screen2(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'


class Screen2(MDScreen):
    def screen1(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'

    def rail_open(self):
        if self.ids.rail.state == "open":
            self.ids.rail.state = "close"
        else:
            self.ids.rail.state = "open"


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

Test().run()
```

**My kv file**

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    Screen1:
        id: screen1
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        id: screen2
        name: 'screen2'

<Screen1>:
    id: screen1
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Change to screen 2"
            on_press: root.screen2()
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}

<Screen2>:
    id: screen2
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: root.rail_open()]]
        MDBoxLayout:
            MDNavigationRail:
                id: rail
                elevation: 1
                use_resizeable: True
                MDNavigationRailItem:
                    icon: "home"
                    text: "homepage"
                    on_press: root.screen1()
                MDNavigationRailItem:
                    icon: ""
                    text: ""
            MDFloatLayout:
                MDTextField:
                    id: field1
                    hint_text: "Enter something:"
                    size_hint_x: 0.4
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.25,'top':0.8}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. Already fixed - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/commit/8a31b0f3ccad9c2d9ad35d80953f7396f2dc78f2